# Bash script crashes when sourcing

Tags: macos, vulkan

[image]I have been following a tutorial about setting up vulcan on macOS and have been having trouble. I think it might have something with the versions. I am using 1.1.101.0 and the tutorial uses 1.1.73.0

here is my /.bash_profile
[image]

Comment: Please transcribe these images as text. This makes your question more accessible and searchable for users with relevant experience to share with you.

Comment: Did you mean something like `./bash_profile` instead of `/.bash_profile`?

Comment: In the `./bash_profile` file, unlike other environment variables, `VULKAN_SDK` and `VK_ICD_FILENAMES` is not followed by `=`. Is that the reason for invalid identifier error?